# With Phaser.js, how detecting if the pointer is a click or scrolling

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch, phaser-framework

When I capture the touch events in the update function (or in callback events), I would differentiate a simple click, of the first click on a scroll.

I am already able to detect the first click of a scroll compared to the next with isClick param on :

```
this.game.input.addMoveCallback ((point, x, y, isClick) => {})
```

But nothing to differentiate a simple click of a first click on a scroll event  :(

I tried with a setTimeout but I not get a great result.
Any other ideas ?

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: I found a workaround for the problem using the library hammerjs

Comment: Why don't you post the solution for others to see?

Comment: @Pixocode - I am struggling with the same problem. Can you share your solution as an answer?